# How to validate XHTML page that using fb:comments ,xid and <div href>?

Tags: php, html, facebook, xhtml

I'm actually gettings these errors and I cannot let them fixed. I need some help. I can't found anything on Google, sorry.

**there is no attribute "href"**

```
<div id="audio" href="http://domain.com/mp3/Green Day - A Quick One While Hes…
```

**there is no attribute "xid"**

```
<div style="margin: 0px 100px;"><fb:comments xid="music52"></fb:comments></div>
```

**element "fb:comments" undefined**

```
<div style="margin: 0px 100px;"><fb:comments xid="music52"></fb:comments></div>
```

Comment: Well, it is not valid XHTML, so there's no chance you'll get it validated in its current form. Where do these things come from? The latter is FBML, I assume, but the former? Why do you need it validated?

Comment: Please also show the PHP code you use to validate the HTML.

Comment: @Pekka seems to be the never finished XHTML2 where every element can have a `href` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot validate this against the standard (x)HTML DocTypes. If anything, this validates against XHTML2, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 2.0//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml2.dtd">
```

This should be the only xHTML flavor that [allows having `href` attributes on any element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-hyperAttributes.html) and that was supposed to have namespace support. Unfortunately, it is also dead.

The only thing you could do is find a schema file or DTD and then validate them as XML, for instance with

- `DOMDocument::schemaValidate` — Validates a document based on a schema
- `DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource` — Validates a document based on a schema
- `DOMDocument::validate` — Validates the document based on its DTD

The alternative would be to not to use the XFBML tags. See

- http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Using_HTML_to_Imitate_XFBML